# Booking accommodation for long term (few months)

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, rental, long-term, airbnb

[Airbnb Sublets](https://airbnb.com/sublets) let you search for long stay accommodation. But it seems that rents are quite high, and not so many options are offered.

Is there an online service that is focusing on accommodation for a long term stay, where a rent would cost the same as if I was a local?

I'm looking for worldwide coverage, but if it doesn't exist, I would like to know more localised ones.

Comment: Do you expect to get the same per-month price as if renting for a whole year?

Comment: @JonathanReez Mhm, no, it could be that some months are more expensive than others.

Comment: The problem with long term accommodation which "costs the same as if I were a local" is that the locals are putting deposits down and signing tenancy agreements - no landlord would risk their property without that, as you rapidly fall into the are of tenants rights in many many jurisdictions the world over.

Comment: This is too broad. The answer is per-country, locals will in general will use local websites.

Comment: Posting as a comment as this is not an answer.  I have found that there are various apartment complexes that offer fully furnished places for business travel, but the price is based on a sliding scale depending on how long you stay.  EG for a 12 month lease you will get the lowest price- what a local would pay.  But as the lease decreases to 1 month the cost rises proportionally to the point that it matches AirBnB rates for whole apartments.  Or you can do unfurnished, but then have to deal with everything from utilities to cutlery yourself.

Comment: The question states looking for websites that work in several to many countries, not in locals only solutions.

Comment: To be clear, locals would be charged the same mid-term rates as out-of-towners.  Where you come from is pretty irrelevant to the proprietor or landlord.  So, you are getting the 'locals' rate already.

Answer (score 4):

I recently was wondering the same and found out about [weroom](https://www.weroom.com).

This is specifically about private rooms in shared flat, not so much about full apartments. Even though it seems to target the local market of medium-term as well as long-term (usually a minimum of a month) accommodation, the fee it takes (around 3% of a rent, if I remember well) makes it more appropriate for the first few months and therefore it is quite appropriate for your request (the price still matches the local market or might be 5-10% higher). It is not available everywhere, it seems mostly available in France, London, Brussels, Montreal. You can still try other places, it might have places available.

I have never tried the service, I have no idea about its quality.

Comment: It's a good service, thanks. The only problem is that is limited to few cities, will see if it grows in the future.

Comment: I think the best way right now, is just contact locals and discover the local city-specific websites with renting ads.

Comment: @Patrick The interesting point about weroom is that in France, to be able to rent an apartment (for long term), you need a lot of guarantees, in particular you need a stable job. Weroom is basically a workaround for this system. Wherever you want to rent, first check what the regulations and particularly what the tradition is.